# ODBC Prepared Statement: CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, prepared-statement, case

I am trying to do a comparison in a MSSQL database using an ODBC driver from PHP. I am trying to compare a user-supplied value with the value that is returned from a CASE expression.

This works:

```
$r = odbc_prepare($link,"SELECT 'success' WHERE
        CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
         = 'foo'
       ");
$s = odbc_execute($r,array());
```

This unfortunately returns an error:

```
$r = odbc_prepare($link,"SELECT 'success' WHERE
        CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
         = ?
       ");
$s = odbc_execute($r,array("foo"));
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation, SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter
```

Comment: What about adding quotes like this `.... END = '?' ` ?

Comment: Sure, I tried that. I don't get an error but it just then takes "?" as the value, rather than using the supplied parameter.

Comment: Have you tried checking prepared statements logs? And maybe try adding `FROM DUAL` to the end of your query? (don't know if this would help but won't hurt to try)

Comment: `FROM DUAL` just returns a syntax error. Isn't that an Oracle thing? And sorry not sure where to look for the logs, could you enlighten me? I have tried running SQL Profiler while running it but it doesn't seem to make an entry there.

Comment: I see that the easiest way is not to use `CASE` which causes some problems with the prepared statements. So instead of doing `WHERE CASE condition THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END = ?` You can do `WHERE ( condition AND foo = ? ) OR ( !condition AND bar = ? )`. Yes you will have to give `array("foo","foo")` as 2nd argument of `execute` but I don't see any other solution :P

Answer (score 0):

When you use parameters in SQL many ODBC wrappers (like the PHP one) will attempt to call SQLDescribeParameter to find out about the parameters. The MS SQL Server ODBC driver attempts to rearrange your SQL into a select statement and then use standard functions to get column type, length etc. For some more complicated SQL or SQL which does not contain tables (like yours, e.g., select 1) it fails to rearrange the SQL into a valid select and you get the error you are getting.

There are 2 solutions: 1) change your SQL so the MS SQL Server ODBC driver can rearrange it into a select 2) change you ODBC wrapper to know this can happen and default to something reasonable. Perl's DBD::ODBC does the latter which means people don't have to do the former.